# How to fill the area of OptionMenu - tkinter

Tags: tkinter, optionmenu

I want to fill the window with grey, however around the OptionMenu there is a missing area which isn't filled.

For example: let's take a simple code that will examine what is my problem.

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
master.config(bg="grey")
variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set("hello")
w = OptionMenu(master, variable, "hello1", "hello2")
w.config(bg="grey")
w.pack()
mainloop()
```

and this is the result:

[image]

I really don't know how to get rid (fill) of the white part.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `highlightthickness = 0` to your `w.config` line will remove the border, but the widget will still appear raised. If you would like to make it totally flat you can also add `relief = FLAT`

Comment: First of all thanks so much! 
There is one thing annoying though, because when I stand with the mouse on the OptionMenu's area it turns to white, can I make it not happening but instead draw the OptionMenu current option word (hello) with blue and background will be grey instead of white? see in post I uploaded now a picture.

Comment: You can do that by adding `activebackground = "grey"` and `fg = "blue"` A useful tip for finding things like this in the future is that if you call config without any parameters (in this case `print(w.config())`) you will get a list of all the config options for that widget.